# split aplhanumeric string for house numbers

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric, split

I need to extract the number range from house number/ unit number.
example - 1B to 36B,
1-B to 36-B or
B1 to B36 or
B 1 to B 36
the result should be 1 to 36

The prefix or postfix characters  or digits can have any length.
ex B150 or B1709 or 150B or
150Block or 1709Block

Please let me know how this can be achieved in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly it *can* be achieved in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to get integer part of the string "600sp"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552756/best-way-to-get-integer-part-of-the-string-600sp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regular expression to do this. Specifically look at character classes , quantifiers , groups and capturing.

Here is a link to the [cheatsheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) .

To get you started here is a "similar" example.

```
String line = "36-B";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d*)(.+)(\\d*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

while (matcher.find()) 
{
    System.out.println("First captured group: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Second captured group: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Thisr captured group: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Let us know if you run into issues. Happy coding !!

Comment: I think string.replaceAll("[^0-9]","") is working for all the cases i can think of to capture the numeric value.

Comment: this regular expression would work fine too.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it.