# Sort string array with numeric and letters

Tags: java, sorting, collections

For example i have List with content:
   {1 5 2b 10 2a 3 7},
and i need sort it in alphabet order as:
   {1 2a 2b 3 5 7 10}. 
I tried with Comparator interface as:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

But it returned array {1 10 2a 2b 3 5 7}. How i can do it in Java?

Comment: Are there any strings where there is no number in front?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1262402/335858) what you are looking for?

Comment: @laune, no, all strings have number in front

Comment: You tried implementing the Comparator interface? Show us the implementation then. The mistake must be in there.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552756/best-way-to-get-integer-part-of-the-string-600sp for how to get the int part, then sort by that.

Comment: @Adrian Leonhard Yes, i tried custom Comparator with override method compareTo, but i need compare string to, for example {2b, 2c, 2a} -> {2a, 2b, 2c}, so i can't use number without letter after

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Thank you ver much for link! NaturalOrderComparator.java is really work  )